# DatePicker on macOS after Esc key is pressed becomes unresponsive / unselectable

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

### Overview

- On macOS when a user clicks on the date in a date picker field a pop up opens with options to select the date if the user taps on Esc key, then there is no option to select that field or any other field.

### Questions:

1. Am I missing something?
2. Is this a bug?

### Steps to reproduce

1. Run the code (see below) on macOS
2. Click on the date portion of the date picker field
3. A pop up opens
4. Press the Esc key

### Actual Behaviour

You can't select the date picker again to change the date.

### Expected Behaviour

When the the escape key is pressed the popup should close and the date picker and other text fields should be selectable again.

### Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var date = Date()
    @State private var note = "hello world"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Birthday", selection: $date)
            TextField("Note", text: $note)
        }
    }
}
```

## Environment:

- macOS: 13.0.1 (22A400)
- Xcode: Version 14.1 (14B47b)

### Screen recording

[image: Date Picker not responding]

Comment: What macOS/Xcode versions are you running?

Comment: @MrDeveloper macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Comment: I've been able to reproduce your issue. Interestingly, I find that you can still edit the `TextField`, but the cursor is hidden. I would suggest filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Yes your observation is correct, I have filed a feedback hope it gets noticed